# How to Install python 2.7 mysql on Digital Ocean

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, digital-ocean

I tried install mysql using this command in my droplet on Digital Ocean:

```
pip install MySQL-python
```

But it not working and show this message:

```
Collecting MySQL-python
  Using cached MySQL-python-1.2.5.zip
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    sh: 1: mysql_config: not found
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-kjiS0F/MySQL-python/setup.py", line 17, in <module>
        metadata, options = get_config()
      File "setup_posix.py", line 43, in get_config
        libs = mysql_config("libs_r")
      File "setup_posix.py", line 25, in mysql_config
        raise EnvironmentError("%s not found" % (mysql_config.path,))
    EnvironmentError: mysql_config not found

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-kjiS0F/MySQL-python/
```

Answer (score 0):

might be issue with the locale settings.
try this:

```
$ export LC_ALL=C
```